# Async functions in ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, async-await

When i request something to the web server via AJAX sometimes the response doesn't come in time for me to put the requested values in a select element:

```
// Fill fornecedor select with options
    async function getFornecedores(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: web_service_url + "/TM_GetEnt?pEntTp=F",
            success: function (data) {
                var xml_node = await $('DocumentElement',data);
                var entnm = [];
                await xml_node.find('Tabela>ENTNM').each(function(){
                    entnm.push($(this).text());
                });
                await xml_node.find('Tabela>ENTCD').each(function(index){
                    $(".fornecedor-select").append($("<option>").text(entnm[index]).val($(this).text()));
                });

            },
            error: function(){
                console.log( "ERROR", arguments );
                console.log(web_service_url);
                alert("Erro");
            }
         });
     }

    // Fill tipo de documento with options
    /*async function getTipoDocumento(){*/
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: web_service_url + "/TM_GetDocTpRecepcao",
            success: function (data) {
                var xml_node = await $('DocumentElement',data);
                var doctpds = [];
                await xml_node.find('Tabela>DOCTPDS').each(function(){
                    doctpds.push($(this).text());
                });
                await xml_node.find('Tabela>DOCTPCD').each(function(index){
                    $(".documento-select").append($("<option>").text(doctpds[index]).val($(this).text()));
                });
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log( "ERROR", arguments );
                alert("Erro");
            }
         });
     /*}*/

     getFornecedores();
     /*getTipoDocumento();*/
```

I tried this in two ways. With an async function and without a function.
I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
Why is this giving me this error if I tried first with two async functions one for each select element? Isn't making it an async function enough for me to await something?

If the async is not the answer to my problems than what is? I get a 500 internal server error. That's not very explicit...

Comment: the syntax error will go away if you put the `async` in the immediately surrounding function, so `success: async (data) => ...`. However, there is really no benefit to using async/await here, the only async code that I can detect here is the $.ajax itself, which you are handling with callbacks.

Comment: So why do my select elements don't get populated sometimes?